# Rudin Functional Analysis Chapter 2 Problem 16

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, closed-graph

Suppose that $X$ and $K$ are metric spaces, and $K$ is compact, and the graph of $f:X\rightarrow K$ is a closed subset of $X\times K$. Prove that $f$ is continuous. Show that compactness of $K$ cannot be omitted from the hypothesis, even when X is compact.

---

My solution: i tried doing it by proving the continuity by sequential criterion and for this i start with a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ converging to some $x\in X$. Then $S=\big(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \{x_{n}\}\big)\cup \{x\}$ is compact subset of X and hence $S^*=\big(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (x_{n},f(x_n))\big)\cup (x,f(x))$ is closed in $X\times K$ and since $(S\cup \{x\})\times K$ is compact hence $S^*$ is compact and hence have a convergent subsequence.
i am not able to move forward. any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that you need only that $K$ is compact. The metric structure does not matter.

Comment: yes you are right. that link solved my problem but can you please tell me how did you find that link this much early?

Comment: I searched closed graph theorem and wiki tells me that your question is really called closed graph theorem in topology. So I search "closed graph theorem topology" and then I get to that.